# How to SET TO_DATE for date and time for date field with multiple values in Oracle/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to execute a query in SQL Developer to update the date and time for a specific value, and only where it has specific attributes for other values. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
update TABLENAME
    Set VALUE1 = to_date('03-APR-21 01:00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH-MI-SS')
    Where VALUE2 in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')
    and VALUE3 = 'Apple'
    and VALUE4 = 'Pear'
```

Does the logic and syntax of this look ok, I can't be a million miles away from getting this right? I get a SQL error advising my statement hasn't been closed out/ended properly, am I missing a semi colon or a COMMIT; or something at the end? My SQL is quite poor - I am trying to improve but struggling with this. Would be grateful for any assistance in phrasing this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You syntax looks fine.  My one recommendation would be to use a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` constant:

```
update TABLENAME
    Set VALUE1 = TIMESTAMP '2021-04-03 01:00:00'
    Where VALUE2 in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green') and
          VALUE3 = 'Apple'
          VALUE4 = 'Pear';
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I've no idea why it keeps telling me my statement hasn't been ended correctly - just wouldn 't let me execute this. I also wanted to make sure for the date and time format I'm using, I'm also correctly specifying the correct date and time format type for it to use (sorry, I don't the correct technical terms for these but I hope you understand what I mean). A colleague advised I think that it should be 'hh:min:ss' for the time. Just realised in my example I've used dashes for the time type when it should be colons.

Comment: @bc1sjw . . . For the constant, the format has to be `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`.